# Is possible to redirect from http to https?

Tags: http, https

I use a site in IIS in https. I use a software, that use a 'HTTP Sender' connector, to connect to my rest.  I need to convert from HTTP to HTTPS.  I have seen that STUNNEL is usually used. I saw that it can be done in stunnel.conf. But I can I do?

Comment: Can you better describe your environment? Is it about a web application? If so, what web server are you using? What do you mean be "redirect .. to https"? Send an HTTP answer with a new URL? Please edit your question and add the additional information.

Comment: I use a site in IIS in https.  I use a software, that use a 'HTTP Sender' connector, to connect to my rest. I need to convert from HTTP to HTTPS.